# Remove the Development tag?

Tags: discussion

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/development

Since the actual development of blender is off topic for this site, I see no reason to have the development tag.

Most of the questions with this tag have been closed, should be closed, or are borderline off topic

Comment: http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2216/source-code-questions-in-2016

Comment: @iKlsR Hmm, I missed that post. We really need to fix the help center (although nobody uses it anyway) I was going off of this post http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-questions-should-be-definitely-off-topic/6#6